# Line Number and attaching single employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

SQL Server 2000 so no `ROW_NUMBER` available ....

I need to attach employees to the free lines.

I have a dataset 1 that tells me the free lines per country and region combo.

Table A – available line numbers to use:

```
Country     Region       Line Number      Employee
---------------------------------------------------
A            1                 1             Null
A            1                 2             Null                           
A            2                 1             Null
```

Table B – what employees are available to fill missing line numbers:

```
Country     Region      Employee
----------------------------------------
A             1         Dave Smith
A             1         Johnny Cash
A             1         Peter Seller 
A             2         David Donald
```

So required output is

Table C - attaching a single employee to each combo of country, region, line number:

```
Country     Region       Line Number         Employee
-------------------------------------------------------------
A            1                 1             Dave Smith
A            1                 2             Johnny Cash                    
A            2                 1             David Donald
```

I tried a lot of joins, including self joins, and cross joins in SQL Server 2000, but can't get the desired output.

This is my last attempt:

```
Select  
    A.Country, A.Region, A.Line Number, 
    B.Employee 
From 
    Table_A A
Inner Join 
    Table_B B On A.Country = B.Country and A.Region = B.Region
```

Comment: Add a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITITON BY Region ORDER BY whatever)` to B and join on the line number in A (if the line numbers are not consecutive you must add another ROW_NUMBER)

Comment: unfortunately not available at sql server 2000 so makes it much harder. Its a legacy system

Comment: You can get a rownumber using `Select (select count(*) from tab as t2 where t1.employee <= t2.employee) as seqnum, ... from tab as t1`. Of course this is not very efficient for large tables and your employee names must be unique.

Comment: @dnoeth - Pop it in as an answer and I can give you points ...

Comment: Have you considered upgrading? SQL 2000 has been out of support for almost a decade now. There have been two major versions released since then that are also out of support.

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional `join` key after `country` and `region` for the assignment.  For this, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select a.*, b.employee
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by country, region order by linenumber) as seqnum
      from table_a a
     ) a join
     (select b.*
             row_number() over (partition by country, region order by (select null) ) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on b.country = a.country and b.region = a.region and b.seqnum = a.seqnum
```

Comment: unfortunately not available at sql server 2000 so makes it much harder. Its a legacy system

Answer (score 1):

Just pulling together all of the suggestions, answers, and comments.

```
--Setting up the tables as given:
CREATE TABLE #e (
  Country  char(1),
  Region int,
  LineNumber int,
  Employee varchar(50));

INSERT #e 
VALUES ('A', 1, 1,NULL)
,('A',1,2,NULL)
,('A',2,1,NULL);

CREATE TABLE #r (
Country char(1),
Region int,
Employee varchar(50));

INSERT #r
VALUES 
 ('A', 1, 'Dave Smith')
,('A', 1, 'Johnny Cash')
,('A', 1, 'Peter Sellers') 
,('A', 2, 'David Donald');

--Creating a temporary table with
--a line number to join on.
CREATE TABLE #T(
LineNumber int,
Country char(1),
Region int,
Employee varchar(50));

--Populate the temporary table
--with the line number data.
INSERT INTO #T
(
  LineNumber,
  Country,
  Region,
  Employee
)
SELECT 
  (SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Line 
   FROM #r AS R2 
   WHERE R2.Employee <= #r.Employee 
    AND R2.Region = #r.Region
  ) AS LineNumber,
  Country,
  Region,
  Employee
FROM #r;

--Set up the final output.
SELECT  
    A.Country, 
    A.Region, 
    A.LineNumber, 
    B.Employee 
FROM 
    #e A
INNER JOIN 
    #T B 
      ON A.Country = B.Country 
      AND A.Region = B.Region
      AND A.LineNumber = B.LineNumber
ORDER BY
  A.Country, 
  A.Region, 
  A.LineNumber;

--Clean up.
DROP TABLE #r;
DROP TABLE #T;
DROP TABLE #e;
```

Results:

```
+---------+--------+------------+--------------+
| Country | Region | LineNumber |   Employee   |
+---------+--------+------------+--------------+
| A       |      1 |          1 | Dave Smith   |
| A       |      1 |          2 | Johnny Cash  |
| A       |      2 |          1 | David Donald |
+---------+--------+------------+--------------+
```